# Why does my "go to work" button not work?

Tags: the-sims-3

When it is time for my Sim to go to work they will not get into the waiting car. I make sure that they are not in the middle of doing something and every time I click on the car to make my Sim go to work the action pannel in the upper left side will disapear and i have tried to click on her work building to force her to go to work but the action panel will still disapear. it won't stay as an active action and i need help fixing this problem

Comment: Do you have any custom content or mods? Does it work if you're standing outside the office building (instead of needing to take a car trip first)? Does it work if you quit your job and then get re-hired?

Comment: Also, what career?

Comment: If their needs are not met (too tired, too depressed, etc.) they can refuse to go to work. Are the needs bars green (or mostly green?)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you see this or found out how to fix the problem (the post is old). But have you tried to click on the dresser and go make an outfit? Then I clicked on the working outfit, but I changed nothing, and then leave the dresser/CAS (outfits) again. This is how I fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the work uniform has been altered somehow.

Quit the job, and then using "testingcheatsenabled true", reset the job by shift+click the mailbox.